# Get all assigned jira ticket on a particular date

Tags: jira, jql

I want to write a jira query (JQL) by which I can get "How many tasks are assigned on a particular date to me and my team members"

For Example, I want to see how many tasks are assigned to me on 22 march?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

To figure out how many tasks were assigned on a particular date you can use `assignee changed ON 'yyyy/MM/dd'`

And to filter issues that were assigned to some specific user, you need to define assignee. Here are some examples:

- `assignee = currentUser()` will get issues assigned to the user running the query (you). And also this is the way to create a universal filter for any of your team member.
- `assignee = username` will get issues assigned to a specific user.
- `assignee in membersOf("groupname")` will get issues that are assigned to the members of Jira group. 
  If you and your team are members of any specific group in Jira, that should do the work.

Now let's combine both parts to one query to get the result. The query filters out all the issues assigned to you on April 1, 2020:

```
assignee = currentUser() AND assignee changed ON '2020/04/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to find issues that were assigned on a certain day, but this is pretty close:

```
assignee in membersOf("your-team-name") AND created = "2020/03/22"
```

Finds all issues that were created on a certain date and that are assigned to anyone on a specific team.

- https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-functions/
- https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-fields/